# How many levels deep can you nest swf's - will 3 work - like child inside parent inside grandparent?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-2

The code at the bottom of this post nests an AS2 "player" inside a Flex app (AS3).  Look at the part that says "[AS2 player swf]".  That AS2 player swf has almost no code - just one function that loads an asset from a remote server.  Very simple:

```
this.onLoad = function(){
    content.loadMovie("http://URL_TO_REMOTE_SWF");
};
```

And it has no other assets.  Just one MovieClip - "content".

So we've got a Flex app that loads an AS2 swf that loads a remote swf.  No dice. Remote swf doesn't load and display.  No errors reported.

Important:  The AS2 app on its own works.  If I go navigate to it in my file system and double click, *remote swf does indeed load and display*.  So I've established that the unwrapped AS2 swf player works and does indeed load remote swf's.  Something about nesting that player inside the Flex app creates a problem.  Are you not allowed to do this - 3 levels of swf nesting (child - parent - grandparent)?

UPDATE:  Target remote swf's load and display fine directly in Flex as well (skipping AS2 swf).  So problem doesn't appear to be with AVM1/AVM2 discrepancy between target content and Flex app.  Could be AVM1/AVM2 problem with how the Flex app displays the AS2 swf but only when it contains content.loadMovie("http://URL_TO_REMOTE_SWF").  Loads and displays without that line.

**UPDATE: This is a Flex packaged IOS application and thus is subject to ActionScript restrictions for dynamically loaded code.  But it doesn't work in a regular Flex (non packaged IOS) app either which is not subject to these limitations.  THE FOLLOWING CODE SHOULD WORK AS FAR AS I CAN TELL IN A REGULAR FLEX BROWSER BASED APPLICATION.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               initialize="init()"> 
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[           
            import mx.core.UIComponent;

            private var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("[AS2 player swf]");
            private var loader:Loader = new Loader();

            private var myComponent:UIComponent = new UIComponent;  

            private function init():void{
                myComponent.percentHeight = 100;
                myComponent.percentWidth = 100;
                loader.load(request);
                myComponent.addChild(loader);
                player.addElement(myComponent);
            }           
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group id="player"
             height="100%" width="100%"/>   

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all Sprites and MovieClips are both display objects and display object containers, you could theoretically keep nesting them forever. There are physical restraints, of course, but I see no reason why there should be a limit other than memory and processing power (at some point, refreshing the screen will become sluggish, and eventually painful to wait for).

I've searched the web to see if I could find any information about a built-in limit enforced by the AVM, any documents or error codes that would suggest there is one, but I couldn't find anything at all.  Of course, that doesn't mean there isn't - it just means the limit hasn't been reached by many people yet ;)
So if anyone else knows more...

**EDIT**

Since the information about your loaded MovieClip is new, here's my update: AVM1 (AS1 & 2) SWFs don't always execute in the same way when loaded into an AVM2 (AS3) movie.  This has nothing to do with the number of nested display objects.  I originally thought this was because the _lockroot property was removed in AS3, but I've searched a bit and found out it is assumed true by default, and should therefore not be a problem.

There may be many things about your scenario that are different from when the file runs on its own, and I would start by looking at these:

- Do you use relative path names to load other data into the AS2 swf?
- Do you get any error messages (particularly, security sandbox violation errors)?
- Does your AS2 SWF rely on external variables to be set (FlashVars)
- Does your AS2 SWF need ExternalInterface access?

**FINAL EDIT**

Since this new info has just come up:

There is **absolutely no way** to execute dynamically loaded AVM byte code on an iPad at runtime, for the same reason that there is no Java VM and no Flash Player for iOS:  Apple does not allow the execution of dynamically loaded byte code at all.  Period.

Hence, you can load and play SWF animations, but not ActionScript.  It will simply be ignored.  Also, neither of the apps that you did run is in fact AVM byte code - [they are compiled into LLVM byte code instead](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html).

You will have to find a way to check for the end of the animation that does not involve stop() commands.  Perhaps this can be done by checking frame numbers from your AS3 container?

Comment: To clarify, new information was revealed.  I posted "Uggghh what a mess.  All I really wanted to do was execute a stop() on an iPad.  I have some AS2 animations that play fine on the iPad, but they don't stop.  They loop because IOS won't execute ActionScript code dynamically from a remote site.  I thought if I could wrap the remote animations in AS2 code included with my AS3 code in my IPA, I could tell that AS2 wrapper code to stop the animation through a LocalConnection bridge."  The original question remains though, because this doesn't work on a plain Flex browser app either.

Comment: My mistaken impression was that the IOS ActionScript limitation applied to dynamically loaded code from **outside** your packaged IPA.  I thought if AS2 code was inside the IPA with my AS3 app it would be cool.  I could just tell IT to stop the dynamically loaded animations through LocalConnection. It's not cool. Just tested. I created an AS2 app with a simple animation with a stop() at the end and loaded it directly into my Flex app.  Packaged that and loaded onto a real iPad.  Stop was ignored.  So even AS packaged into your IPA won't execute.  My apologies to weltraumpirat for my ommission.

Comment: On weltraumpirat's notion of checking for the end of animation without stop(), that's what I was after - somehow reaching into the AS2 animation from the outside and stopping it.  Can't do it from the AS3 container because can't query AS2 animation's frame numbers.  Can only communicate AS3 to AS2 via calling functions across a LocalConnection.  There are none in the AS2 animations to call though.  I thought if I put one in the AS2 wrapper that checked if currFrame==LastFrame I could issue a stop from outside when true.  Can't get AS2 wrapper code to execute though.  Any way to compile AS2 in?

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question directly, yes, you can load AS2 swfs that way. And you code looks correct to me.

I suspect it is loading the AS2 swf fine, but that the AS2 swf is not initializing correctly for some reason. Perhaps it is a video player that has no visible assets besides the loaded video. AS2 tends to fail without throwing errors, which makes it hard to debug. I would suggest publishing an AS2 swf with some graphics in it but with no code that could fail. No code at all. Maybe just a timeline animation of a moving circle or something, then load that. In that way you can eliminate your Flex code as the source of the problem.

If it turns out that your test movie works, then you will need to determine what resource the loaded swf is expecting that it is not receiving.

Comment: Good point.  Did exactly that.  Made AS2 swf that just contained a square shape that moved across the screen.  This loads fine in Flex code so we can assume the Flex code is OK. Note the corrected version of my orig post above though.  The AS2 player swf just has one function in it.  All it does is load the remote asset.  No complicated code in it that might fail.  Note as well that a JPG DOES NOT work as I initially reported.  My mistake.  It fails the same as if I point to a remote swf.  AS2 swf does load and display remote swf successfully if I run on its own - not nested in Flex.  Hmmm...

Comment: I wonder what could be breaking the as2 code. I suspect it has something to do with the use of _globals, or _root. Or perhaps it is even trying to access _parent. All of which would work differently if the as2 swf was loaded into an as3 parent. It could also be referencing the stage before it is added to the display list. But again, as2 does not throw errors. Do you have access to the as2 source? Otherwise, try a decompiler to take a look at what it does.

Comment: I wrote the AS2 source so yes I have access.  Again, as indicated in the original post, there are no _globals or _root or referencing the stage.  AS2 source is basically one line of code - content.loadMovie("http://URL_TO_REMOTE_SWF");  There should be absolutely nothing objectionable about that.

Comment: Think I found it:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html
The AVM1 content cannot load files into levels. For example, it cannot load files by calling loadMovieNum("url", levelNum).
"The AVM1 SWF file that is loaded by an AVM2 SWF file cannot load another SWF file into this. That is, it cannot load another SWF file over itself. However, child Sprite objects, MovieClip objects, or other AVM1 SWF files loaded by this SWF file can load into this."

Comment: Hmmmm....  I'm not much of a Flash guy and don't know much about levels. I guess what this is saying is that if you load an older swf into a newer one, that older one can't load swf's because it doesn't have a notion of stacking things. It'll sort of overwrite itself.  Is that a fair assessment?  If so, that kind of answers this question.  I guess if an AS3 swf loads an AS3 swf, that second swf could load more.  But if an AS3 swf loads an AS2, that's where the chain has to end. Sound about right?

Comment: Wish you had mentioned iOS before. There is no loading of external swfs in iOS. Thanks, Apple. But for regular flash, or AIR, its permitted with some resrictions on AS2 code.